# Java SAXParserFactory.newInstance() in WildFly 11 error

Tags: wildfly, saxparser

I had project trying to convert a docx to xml. I am using Java 8 and WildFly 11 with using the SAXParserFactory but there is error when I run the code.

Code:

```
  private static SAXParser SAX_PARSER;
  static {
    try {
      SAX_PARSER = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(
          "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl", null)
          .newSAXParser();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-17) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Testing2/jsp/docxToXmlTesting.do: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
            at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at company.test.DocXToXML.<clinit>(DocXToXML.java:270)
            at docxToXmlTesting.Action.docxToXmlTesting.execute(docxToXmlTesting.java:89)
            at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
            at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
            at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
            at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
            at company.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:24)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
            at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
            at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl from [Module "deployment.Testing2.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 54 more
```

It show "javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found".

I had try to add "import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl;" in the java, and it compile with no error. But run the source still get this error message.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using an old implementation of this ... But on this page, it will tell you a list of dependencies you could include (you only need one) to get this class: https://www.findjar.com/class/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl.html - and here's a tutorial on parsing using SAX for Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Comment: You are referring to an internal JDK class which is not 'available' per default to your application as jboss modules only expose the API not the implementations. I guess you should add a dependency on the correct module for this. Also I'm not sure about the interest in your code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had change the class to be "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl", and then no error exists. It seems no problem now.